# Apache URL rewrite change file extension from .htm to .cfm

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, httpd.conf

First let me apologize if this has been asked/answered before.  I did a search and could not find what I was looking for.  Some questions were close but just not enough.  Again apologies for duplication.

Second, my work has always been with IIS and as such my apache knowledge is limited so again, my apologies for asking for a little extra "hand holding" as I learn how to address this issue.  Much thanks to any and all for your help.

Now for my question...

I have **http://www.mycompany.com/internalUser/[className]/beginClass.htm** where [className] is dynamic, for example **French101** or **Biology210** but each always have **beginClass.htm**
What I need to do is have a URL rewrite that changes beginClass.***htm*** to beginClass.***cfm***

What I am not sure of is where should this rewrite code go - in the httpd.conf or .htaccess file within /internalUser folder.

Furthermore, I have tried the following example adding it to the directory tag created for internalUser

-- Copied from httpd.conf

```
Alias /internalUser "c:/iUser/training"
<Directory "c:/iUser/training">
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase "/iUser/training"

    RewriteCond "$1.cfm" -f
    RewriteCond "$1.htm" !-f
    RewriteRule "^(.*).htm$" "$1.cfm"
</Directory>
```

Also created in .htaccess file and neither is working.  When I attempt to open the .htm it does not redirect or open the .cfm version.  The .htm file is still being opened.

Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

Use below for rewrite,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^internalUser/([^\/]+)/beginClass.cfm$ internalUser/$1/beginClass.htm [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Where would this go?  httpd.conf or .htaccess file?  So far I have not been able to determine where these rewrite rules should go.  Thank you

Comment: Try it in your root .htaccess.